# How can tell the difference between the link and the footnote using C# ITextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a simple PDF file that has the Link and the Footnote on a page. When I run the annotation check using iTextSharp, both of the links return the sub type as Link. Is there a way to tell the difference between those two items?

I did examine through an intellisence the structure of an annotation dictionary and notice the annotation object dictionary for the Footnote has once extra item, which is named "F", and that item has a value of 4. That item is NOT present at all in the annotation dictionary for the Link. Can I use the 'F' item/parameter as a way to tell the difference between the Link and the Footnote?

Thank you very much in advance

[Here is the PDF file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RBz2-pcJvHqG3AAKmPu1PP2bnxwOvIyI/view?usp=sharing)

Here is our code

```
    public string AnyPDFCheckComments(string inFileName, string strUsername, string strFilename)
    {
            string strCommentType = string.Empty;
            string strWidgetFound = string.Empty;
            string strPageNumber = string.Empty;
            string message = string.Empty;
            string strComments = string.Empty;
            string strCommentsFound = string.Empty;
            int intCommentCount = 0;

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFileName);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; ++i)
            {
                strPageNumber = i.ToString();

                PdfDictionary pagedic = reader.GetPageN(i);

                PdfArray annotarray = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pagedic.Get(PdfName.ANNOTS));

                if (annotarray == null || annotarray.Size == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Finding out the links
                foreach (object annot in annotarray.ArrayList)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annotationDic = null;
                    if (annot is PdfIndirectReference)
                    {
                        annotationDic = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject((PdfIndirectReference)annot);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        annotationDic = (PdfDictionary) annot;
                    }

                    PdfName subType = (PdfName)annotationDic.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
                    if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.TEXT)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("text") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "text";
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if ((subType.Equals(PdfName.LINK)) && (strCommentsVariables.IndexOf("Link") != -1))
                    {
                        strCommentType = "Link";
                        //break;
                    }

                    if ((strCommentType != ""))
                    {
                        strCommentsFound = "Yes";
                        intCommentCount = ++intCommentCount;
                        strComments = strComments + "<BR>" + "A comment type of '" + "<b>" + strCommentType + "</b>" + "' has been found on page no: " + "<b>" + strPageNumber + "</b>";
                        if (intCommentCount == 5)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strCommentType = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return strComments;
    }
```

Comment: Well, both are links, aren't they? You may want to differentiate between links opening a remote website and links with a destination inside the same document. But there is no special "footnote" link type in pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for us

```
var footnoteIdentifier = annotationDic.Get(PdfName.F);
if (footnoteIdentifier != null)
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: That that works is purely by accident. Any annotation can have flags. If you only work on a single pdf or on a collection of pdfs produced by the same program, that code might be ok for you. If you will eventually have to work with documents from the wild, you'll get both false negatives and false positives.